# Is it possible to use ng-pattern with a variable

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm terrible with regular expressions but I was wondering if it was possible to use ng-pattern with a variable

For example,

```
ng-pattern="/^{{validationCode}}$/"
```

where validationCode is a variable attached to $scope in a controller

```
// Inside Controller
$scope.validationCode = 'response returned from server'
```

If

```
$scope.validationCode = 1234123412351234
```

then the ng-pattern would be

```
ng-pattern="/^1234123412351234$/"
```

But this isn't working and it seems like I need to create a custom directive which I don't really want

Comment: Oh...you know what... I think I found a similar question...crap  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`ng-pattern` expects a regex expression.

From Angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) about `ng-pattern`:

> Sets pattern validation error key if the value does not match the `RegExp` pattern expression. Expected value is `/regexp/` for inline patterns or `regexp` for patterns defined as scope expressions.

In other words, you could create a RegExp in the controller:

```
$scope.pattern = new RegExp(patternFromServer);
```

and use it:

```
<input ng-model="foo" ng-pattern="pattern">
```